# Multiple endpoint support in camel 3.0.0-m2 required?

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

Earlier in version 2.1x, from() was having String[] as parameter, but now at 3.0.0-m2 that feature is removed (only 1 endpoint can be given)
Could you please advice how to handle multiple endpoints in from() ?

Answer (score 0):

This was not fully implemented and endorsed in Camel 1.x btw. In Camel 2 it has been removed and you should conform to 1 endpoint per route.

Also make sure to read the migration guide which you can find on github